# Wow, my Android OS used 1.75GB in 5 days

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, data-monitoring

I just purchased a samsung galaxy s2 from Virgin Mobile on the 7th of May 2013. Have it activated on the 8th of May 2013. Can anyone tell me why my Android OS would have used up 1.75 GB of data in that amount of time. Not to mention the slow data speeds I am  receiving I could barely download anything unless I waited a very long time and had very poor internet connections. was constantly getting webpage not available every time I used the Google search. Have had many conversations with virgin mobile to no avail. Can anyone help or at least explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: If you're speaking of 1,75GB data being transfered (and not of 1,75GB of storage used up), and at the same time speaking of "slow data speed", that's almost a contradiction: at an average 2G speed of 100kBit, that would mean a ~40.8h transfer. Maybe it *felt* slow to you (as background transfers used most of your bandwidth, see GAThrawn's answer)? You also didn't specify what kind of connection (2g/3g/4g) you have, what speed limit your provider has set, and what volume your data plan includes before getting throttled.

Answer (score 3):

Phones always use more data than normal in the first day or so, particularly if you didn't connect it to wifi while it was being set up.

Things that happen in the first day will be checking for (and downloading and installing) OS updates (which can be large), downloading and installing new apps (some of which could be large), syncing data down from the cloud to apps for the first time, syncing data and apps down from backed up Android data to your device.

You might also want to see these previous questions for more info:

- [How to monitor the amount of data traffic?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-to-monitor-the-amount-of-data-traffic)
- [Minimizing data usage for users with data caps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9717/minimizing-data-usage-for-users-with-data-caps)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm guessing you went to the "Data Usage" option in the Settings Menu in order to find out how much data has been transferred.

If so, this screen will also list each of the applications that participated in that transfer and how much each one has transferred. Look for the one(s) that did most of this huge transfer.

If they're non-standard apps (like Chrome, Maps, etc), disable them: Settings->Apps->All, click on app, click "Disable" and "Force Stop". Or better yet just uninstall them.

If they are standard apps, but you thing they're doing a lot more transfer than they should (i.e. Chrome transferring 1 gb in one day) you may have some virus or exploit or something like that. In that case you could try one ofthe AV programs:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Android+Antivirus&hl=en

though I've never tried any of those myself so I can't tell you how good they are. One other way to go in this situation is to wipe out everything (do a factory reset).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, the problem is from apps running in the background. I'.m using the S4 on Android 4.2.2 
This fixed the problem for me Got to SETTINGS\CONNECTIONS\DATA USAGE scroll and you will see all App's running and their offending data usage on the right of the screen. In my case vMYeyePro was using large amounts of background data 1.2gb in  a week. Tap on the App scroll to the bottom and you will see RESTRICT BACKGROUND DATA put a tick in this box and Voilà

Jobe done